# Shutdown, logout, restart not working in 13.10

Tags: unity, compiz, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and have installed compiz settings manager and cairo dock. The top right corner which gives you option for

1. about this computer
2. system settings
3. shutdown
4. restart
5. logout and others seems to have a problem

All options are working except shutdown, logout, suspend, restart. Whenever I click on them nothing happens and sometimes this icon disappears from this tray.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @olli you really think this question should remain open?

Comment: @Braiam: I'm not sure why it should be closed. Except well, uh, it's bug report, I guess.

Comment: @Olli please read this http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8119/please-dont-use-the-edit-button-in-the-close-queue-to-correct-typos-or-improve

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, and I personally did not like the [hack](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112/comments/17) proposed at [the associated bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112) by user Fabounet (cf. [UBod's answer](/a/370998#223688)), mainly because it means you have to apply the hack again and again each time you update Cairo dock.

I came up with a (in my opinion) cleaner workaround, which I also posted at the bug report. It basically involves adding another item to the panel which also has Shutdown/Logout/Suspend/Restart functionality:

1. Hold down <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, right click on the Gnome panel, and click on **Add to Panel...** in the menu that pops up.
2. In the drop-down list that appears, look for the item **User menu** (described as *Menu to change your settings and online status*), select it, and click **Add**.

This will add a *user menu* to your panel. It shows as an item displaying your name with a speech bubble beside it.

The nifty thing is that this item also got menu points for *Switch user*, *Log out* and *Power off* (the latter of which lets you choose between *Supend*, *Restart* and *Shutdown*), **and these work**, as opposed to the same entries of the "default" gear-wheel item in the upper right corner of the panel.

Comment: Where did you buy your keyboard ? Sorry but I have no "Super" button on mine.

Comment: Hi. Don't remember where I bought it, but it's a fairly standard one. Most PC keyboards nowadays have a Super key. See [this Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#mediaviewer/File:ANSI_Keyboard_Layout_Diagram_with_Form_Factor.svg) for a typical keyboard layout with Super key. The Super key oftentimes has a Windows logo on it, as it is the key which opens up the Start menu in Windows. Therefore I think some people refer to it as the "Windows key", though that is a misnaming, particularly in a Linux community. Personally I even glued little Tux'es over the Windows logos ;)

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not the one who came up with this workaround, it might still be useful for readers of this thread to know about it (posted on https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112 by user "Fabounet"):

```
edit /usr/lib/cairo-dock/cairo-dock-launcher-API-daemon as root
add the following line at line 33:
from time import sleep
and the following line at line 241 (just before ULWatcher()):
sleep(5)
```

BTW, I use a x86_64 system. In this case, the path of the file is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairo-dock/cairo-dock-launcher-API-daemon`.

Hope it helps.